# how to see the deleted files using Git Bash?

Tags: git

I want to know all or I want to list all the deleted files in my repository, but I don't know how to do that using Git Bash, I want to know what I'm gonna type in command using Git Bash?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this command to list all deleted files

`$ git reflog`

type that code in your Git Bash

Comment: Thank you. it's helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `grep` binary installed you can list only the deleted files using:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete
```

Without `grep` you will see also the commit information, with:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary
```